# Not Initiating C++ two dimension arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

My case is really simple, in fact I am unable to find an optimal solution for it.

In the code I'm developing I must create a two dimensional array in this way (our teacher said it must be implemented this way):

```
while{
  if(first_case){
    int number_of_elements<<INPUT;
    int double_array[number_of_elements][number_of_elements];
  }else{
  //NOW WE WORK WITH THE double_array
  }
}
```

The thing is that obviously the program doesn't compile because the loop may not access the first "if" before going to the "else". On the other hand, I can't leave without initiating a two dimensional array in c++.

I am pretty lost right now and I would much appreciate any help you may provide.

Comment: Initialize your `double_array` in the `else {}` block.  If you need it in both, initialize it before the `if{}` block

Comment: Your professor is wrong. C++ only supports *Variable Length Arrays* (VLAs) through NON-Standard compiler extension. The C++ Standard does not provide for their use.. `std::vector<std::vector <int>>` will, or, not recommended, you can use `new/delete[]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is so simple, yet it didn't come to my mind

Comment: *our teacher said it must be implemented this way* -- That code is wrong.  Have your teacher try this trick with Visual C++, and they will rightly be greeted with a compiler error.